# Modify expression so it can act in a group of points with a value in common

Tags: qgis, point, expression, aggregate

Can somebody help me to modify this expression so it can act in a group of points with a value in common? As it is right now it numbers the points extracted from a line based on the northernmost point clockwise, but it takes all the points from the layer. I wished it did something as in the image bellow.

```
if (
    vertex_index < 
    aggregate( 
        @layer, 
        'max',
        vertex_index,
        $y = maximum( $y)
    ),
    vertex_index + ( aggregate (
        @layer,
        'count',
        vertex_index
    ) - aggregate ( 
            @layer, 
            'max',
            vertex_index,
            $y = maximum( $y)
    )),
    vertex_index - aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'max',
        vertex_index,
        $y = maximum( $y)
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression you give you have to calculate your 'max' and 'count' `by id`.

Add an additional field and try to use the following expression :

```
if (
    vertex_index < 
    maximum(vertex_index,id,$y=maximum($y,id)),
    vertex_index + (
    count(vertex_index,id)
    - maximum(vertex_index,id,$y=maximum($y,id))
    ),
    vertex_index - maximum(vertex_index,id,$y=maximum($y,id))
)
```

I haven't been able to obtain a **group by** using the aggregate functions of QGIS. If anybody knows how to do that i would be glad to have the information ...

*Given your previous question you used **extract vertices**. Don't forget you will have a set of two 'duplicate' vertices for each polygon.*

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @snaileater: for a group_by you can use the collect($geometry, group_by:="id") expression which will collect the geometries with the same id into a multigeometry object.

Comment: @eurojam : thanks i'll give it a try ...

Answer (score 3):

The standard aggregate function of QGIS expression has no `group_by` argument. You have to use other aggregate functions. You can do this in the following steps. Its explained in a way to create a new field for each step you can refer to in the next steps. However, you could also concatenate the expression to one long expression to perform it all at once.

1. Create a field `y` for the value of the y-coordinate for each point: `$y`
2. Create a new field `line_id` to assign to each vertex the id of the line it belongs to: `array_first (overlay_intersects( 'line', $id))` where `line` is the name of the original line layer.
3. Find the value of the y-coordinates of the northernmost vertex **for each line**: `maximum( $y, group_by:=line_id)` and create a new field `northernmost_y_per_line` with it.
4. Get the `vertex_index` value of the northernmost point and create a new field called`northernmost_vertex_per_line`:

```
attribute (
    get_feature(
        @layer, 
        'y',
        northernmost_y_per_line
    ),
    'vertex_index'
)
```

5. Count the number of vertices per line and create a new field called `no_of_vertices_per_line`:

```
count( 
    vertex_index,
     line_id
)
```

6. Now assign a new_vertex_index to each point following this rule (pseudocode):

```
if (
    vertex_index < northernmost_vertex_per_line,
    vertex_index - northernmost_vertex_per_line + number of vertices per line,
    vertex_index - northernmost_vertex_per_line
)
```

Or actual code with expressions:

```
if (
    vertex_index < northernmost_vertex_per_line,
    vertex_index - northernmost_vertex_per_line + no_of_vertices_per_line,
    vertex_index - northernmost_vertex_per_line
)
```

[image]

Comment: Vielen Dank ! ..